# STS:Class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource' not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

i am new to spring java

Here is the Code:

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.shr</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<name>SpringDemoProject</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


 <!-- MySQL database driver -->
 <dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.8</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
</dependencies>
</project>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerdetails" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="customerDAO" class="com.shr.customer.dao.impl.JdbcCustomerDAO">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Model Class :Customer.java

```
-package com.shr.customer.model;

public class Customer {
int custId;
String name;
int age;

public Customer(int custId,String name,int age)
{
    this.custId=custId;
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
}

//getter and setter methods

public int getCustId() {
    return custId;
}
public void setCustId(int custId) {
    this.custId = custId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

interface class :CustomerDao

```
package com.shr.customer.dao;

import com.shr.customer.model.Customer;



public interface CustomerDAO {

public void insert(Customer customer);
public Customer findByCustomerId(int custId);

}
```

Class implementing the interface

```
package com.shr.customer.dao.impl;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import com.shr.customer.dao.CustomerDAO;
import com.shr.customer.model.Customer;

public class JdbcCustomerDAO implements CustomerDAO
{
private DataSource dataSource;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public void insert(Customer customer){

    String sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER " +
            "(CUST_ID, NAME, AGE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, customer.getCustId());
        ps.setString(2, customer.getName());
        ps.setInt(3, customer.getAge());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }
    }
}

public Customer findByCustomerId(int custId){

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUST_ID = ?";

    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, custId);
        Customer customer = null;
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            customer = new Customer(
                rs.getInt("CUST_ID"),
                rs.getString("NAME"), 
                rs.getInt("Age")
            );
        }
        rs.close();
        ps.close();
        return customer;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
            conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }
    }
}
 }
```

and finally the Main Class

```
package com.shr.common;


  import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.shr.customer.dao.CustomerDAO;
import com.shr.customer.model.Customer;

public class App {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");

        CustomerDAO customerDAO = (CustomerDAO) context.getBean("customerDAO");
        Customer customer = new Customer(1, "mkyong",28);
        customerDAO.insert(customer);

        Customer customer1 = customerDAO.findByCustomerId(1);
        System.out.println(customer1);
}

}
```

Because of the above mentioned error I am not able to move ahead with code.please suggest me how should i resolve it.

I changed the dependency for sql with several versions still it did not work.Please tell me what all dependencies i need to add in `pom.xml` to run a database oriented program?

I am using `mysql` as database.
I have pasted entire code so check if any other mistake.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

pom is missing Spring-JDBC module

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have no dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```